# How to specify default global variable alignment for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, alignment

How do I get rid of alignment (`.align 4` below) for all global variables by default with GCC, without having to specify `__attribute__((aligned(1)))` for each variable?

I know that what I ask for is a bad idea to apply universally, becuase on some architectures an alignment of 1 wouldn't work, because e.g. the CPU is not able to dereference an unaligned pointer. Bit in my case I'm writing an i386 bootloader, and unaligned pointers are fine (but slower) there.

Source code (`a.c`):

```
__attribute__((aligned(1))) int answer0 = 41;
int answer = 42;
```

Compiled with: `gcc -m32 -Os -S a.c`

Assembly output (`a.s`):

```
    .file   "a.c"
    .globl  answer
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   answer, @object
    .size   answer, 4
answer:
    .long   42
    .globl  answer0
    .type   answer0, @object
    .size   answer0, 4
answer0:
    .long   41
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The flag `gcc -fpack-struct=1` changes the alignment of all struct members and structs to 1. For example, with that flag

```
struct x { char a; int b; };
struct y { int v : sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) == sizeof(struct x); };
struct z { int b; };
struct x x = { 1, 1 };
int i = 42;
struct z z = { 2 };
```

compiles to no alignment for variables `x' and`z', but it still has an `.align 4` for the variable `i` (of type `int`). I need a solution which also makes `int i = 42;` unaligned, without having to specify something extra for each such variable.

Comment: Is editing the linker directive file for your project an option?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Yes, editing the linker script (i.e. the `-Wl,-T,foo.scr`) is doable.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do, but here you're just plain shooting yourself in the foot. C doesn't allow variables to be freely aligned. The `__attribute__((aligned(1)))` is nothing but a broken hack, and even the GCC bug tracker acknowledges it.

Comment: ... because there is no way to tell the compiler that every pointer is unaligned as well...

Comment: aligned(1) does not make any sense. It is always true for any alignment. I assume that you do not understand how this attribute works. As I see the default alignment is 4. When compiler & linker see your directive it uses the default alignment as both align 4 and align 1 are the same in this case. To force variable of the size 4 to be placed between variables with size of x*4 at the odd address much more effort is needed.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: I'm writing an i386 bootloader, and unaligned variables and unaligned pointers are OK (but can be slow) in this architecture.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: aligned(1) does indeed make sense in my use case. I'm writing an i386 bootloader, and unaligned variables and unaligned pointers are OK (but can be slow) in this architecture. Do you happen to know how to make all global variables unaligned?

Comment: @pts read the whole comment. This attribute does nothing in your case.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: `aligned(1)` does indeed make a difference in my case. I'm writing my own GNU ld linker script with all sections having `: ALIGN(1) SUBALIGN(1)`, and when I specify `__attribute__((aligned(1)))` for a global variable, some `\0`s get removed from the output executable. Thus I'm still looking for the answer to my question, because that would make difference for me.

Comment: Nothing you say makes any sense. I've written an i386 bootloader too, and I absolutely still don't get why you'd need to misalign everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably gcc doesn't have such a flag which can change the default alignment of global variables.

`gcc -fpack-struct=1` can be a workaround, but only for global variables which happen to be of `struct` type.

Also post-processing the `.s` output of gcc and removing (some of) the `.align` lines could work as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

IMO packing variables to save the space using the packed struct is the easiest and safest way.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define _packed __attribute__((packed))


_packed struct 
{
    uint8_t x1; 
    _packed int x2;
    _packed uint8_t x3[2];
    _packed int x4;

}byte_int;

int main(void) {
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &byte_int.x1, &byte_int.x2, &byte_int.x3, &byte_int.x4);
    printf("%u %u %u %u\n", (unsigned int)&byte_int.x1, (unsigned int)&byte_int.x2, (unsigned int)&byte_int.x3, (unsigned int)&byte_int.x4);    // I know it is an UB just to show the op in dec - easier to spot the odd and the even addresses

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/bY1soH

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is one way to have unaligned `int`s. Another way is to declare each int with `__attribute__((aligned(1)))`, and adding `: ALIGN(1) SUBALIGN(1)` to each section of the linker script. Both of these requires a manual enumeration of all global variables in the C codebase, and making changes to each declaration manually. In this question I want to avoid that: I'd like to make all global C variables unaligned *by default*. The end result would be that gcc doesn't generate the `.align 4` line in the assembly output *by default*. This answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: it is architecture defined. Doing all sections not properly aligned is the very dangerous and improper way. But it is your choice.

Comment: Why do you think it's very dangerous in an i386 bootloader? Why is it improper?

Comment: @pts the compiler does assume an alignment, unless it is very b0rken. Even packed structs are potentially b0rken if you pass a pointer to a member. The only guarantee you might have is that you're perhaps not using a SSE/MMX instruction that would crash when unaligned

Comment: SSE/MMX inthe bootloader? What for?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I use only the normal (non-SSE, non-MMX, non-floating point) registers of the i686 (Pentium Pro) in my bootloader. Unalingned memory access works with these. I don't mind the speed penalty.

Comment: The thing is, you still need to tell the compiler explicitly that it is using stuff unaligned, otherwise compiler might still use some silly stuff to align pointers for example for memcpy.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: I don't fully understand your comment. It certainly doesn't apply to memcpy, which works with analigned pointers on i386. It's also unlikely that we need additional gcc flags, because I've tried it: after compilation and linking I moved everything by 1 byte in memory, and it has still worked (because it used position-independent code) even though now everything was misaligned. Given that, could you please clarify which compiler flag you propose and why?

Comment: @PeterJ_01: FYI I've added `-fpack-struct=1` to the question, which can be useful when combined with your answer.

Comment: I am unable to produce an error because it seems that my GCC doesn't care about aligning `rep movsl` for moving shorts for memcpy intrinsic.